# Conditionally dropping duplicates using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks as such:

| header1 | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | 1 | True |
| val2 | 2 | True |
| val1 | 1 | True |
| val2 | 2 | False |

and I want to conditionally deduplicate the rows, based upon if the last column is `True` or not.

In the above table I want the output dataframe after drops to look like this:

| header1 | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | 1 | True |
| val2 | 2 | True |
| val2 | 2 | False |

having deduplicated the third row, as it had header 3 set to true, but not the fourth row, as it had header 3 set to false.

I haven't yet been able to figure out how to do this, as `drop_duplicates` doesn't support this explicitly and it's not generally good practice to iterate through an entire dataframe (although I will if I have to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep all duplicated rows if header is False, this should work

```
# flag the row if header3 is not False or duplicated
df = df[~df['header3'] | ~df.drop(columns='header3').duplicated()]
print(df)
  header1  header2  header3
0    val1        1     True
1    val2        2     True
3    val2        2    False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [606]: ix = df[df['header3']].drop_duplicates().index
In [610]: df = pd.concat([df.loc[ix], df[~df['header3']]])

In [611]: df
Out[611]: 
  header1  header2  header3
0    val1        1     True
1    val2        2     True
3    val2        2    False
```